# How to point to a sprites folder outside the project directory?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, sprite

I have a compass project set up in a sub-directory (/project/sub1/sub2/sub3/sub4/). The SCSS files are located at /project/sub1/sub2/sub3/sub4/css/src and images are at /project/sub1/sub2/sub3/sub4/images.

I need to generate a sprite whose source PNGs are saved in a directory outside of the project (/project/sub1/sub2/sub3/alternate-sub4/images/global). I tried changing the path around for my @import, but it keeps throwing an error when compiling my SCSS that says "no files were found in the load path..".

Here is my @import in _sprites.scss:

@import "/../../../alternate-sub4/images/global/*.png";

My config.rb is located at /project/sub1/sub2/sub3/sub4/

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "css/src"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
fonts_dir = "fonts"
```

Can somebody tell me what I need to change to get this to work? I have tried many different things including symbolic links and pointing to the directory using sprite_load_path, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: have you tried the full path?

Comment: Yes, that's the only thing that I could get to work, however it needs to work for other devs, so it has to be relative to the project directory.

Comment: Have you tried symbolic links?

Comment: I think your paths should be something like css_dir = "~/css/" OR "/css/"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an additional path where Compass will look for sprites, using the following configuration:

```rb
sprite_load_path << '../alternate-sub4/images'
```

or

```rb
sprite_load_path << File.expand_path('../alternate-sub4/images')
```

And in your SCSS file, import the PNGs files:

```
@import 'global/*.png';
```

See the [configuration reference](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/).

**Note:**
The `sprite_load_path` directive is an `Array` which is why the addition of a path is made using the Ruby operator `<<`.

Comment: I had added this line "sprite_load_path = "/Volumes/Macintosh \HD/Sites/project/sub1/sub2/sub3/alternate-sub4/images/" 
" to my config.rb file, but I can only get it to work if the full-path is defined. Any ideas how to make it so it's relative to the project directory? I tried "../", but no dice. :(

Comment: @user2113311 Oops, I badly written the additional path. Note that the `sprite_load_path` directive is an `Array` which is why the addition of a path is made using the Ruby operator `<<`.